# VB.Net equivalent for (CustomizationContext) in VBA

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word, automation, interop

I'm busy with some word automation and have run into an issue whereby a context menu within a document has items in, that I wish to remove.

Once the document is open, through vba I can remove these items by running the following code;

[VBA]

```
Dim oContextMenu As CommandBar
Dim oContextMenuItem As CommandBarControl

'Make changes to the ActiceDocument only (this is needed to make any changes to this document).
CustomizationContext = ActiveDocument

For Each oContextMenu In ActiveDocument.CommandBars

    If oContextMenu.Type = MsoBarType.msoBarTypePopup Then 'Loop through all the context menus of type (msoBarTypePopup)

        For Each oContextMenuItem In oContextMenu.Controls

            If (InStr(oContextMenuItem.Caption, "Smokeball")) Then
                oContextMenuItem.Delete
            End If

        Next

    End If

Next
```

If I execute this code and check the document, all contextMenu sub items that contain the text "smokeball" are removed.

When I try move this code to my VB.NET solution (I have no choice of language, so VB it is), I get errors on the `CustomizationContext = ActiveDocument` line (this line has to be there for it to affect the current document).

The error I get is `CustomizationContext' is not a by reference property.`

Does anyone know how to get just that ONE line equivalent for vb.net?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: In case you need to see the vb.net sub:**

```
        Private Sub RemoveUnwantedContextMenuItems()

            Dim oContextMenu As CommandBar
            Dim oContextMenuItem As CommandBarControl

            'Make changes to the ActiceDocument only (this is needed to make any changes to this document).
            WordApplication.CustomizationContext = WordApplication.ActiveDocument 'This is the error.

            For Each oContextMenu In WordApplication.CommandBars

                If oContextMenu.Type = MsoBarType.msoBarTypePopup Then 'Loop through all the context menus of type (msoBarTypePopup)

                    For Each oContextMenuItem In oContextMenu.Controls

                        If (InStr(oContextMenuItem.Caption, "Smokeball")) Then
                            oContextMenuItem.Delete()
                        End If

                    Next

                End If

            Next

        End Sub
```

PS - I have also already tried using the  `.AttachedTemplate` as well as `.Normal / .NormalTemplate`

Comment: I'd love for whom ever gave this question a -1 to please give some explanation... There has been close to a day and half spent on research for this topic.

Comment: has WordApplication been initialised and opened?

Comment: @Jules Yes, I'm already using it in other areas at this stage.

Comment: Is ActiveDocument still open at this stage?  Try Console.WriteLine(WordApplication.Documents.Count) before the problem line.

Comment: @Jules Yes the ActiveDocument is open at this stage.
The result from your `Console.WriteLine` = 1

Comment: Strange, I can't replicate the issue here is the code I used https://codeshare.io/Y4g31

Comment: @Jules Yup, tested your code - works perfectly fine. Using my existing WordApplication object, I still get the same error... Very weird.
PS - Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jules pointed me in the right direction with his sample code.
After lots of playing around I noticed that somewhere in the solution, the `[TYPE]` of WordApplication was getting changed to a dynamic type of sorts, hence, it couldn't use `CustomizationContext`.

My solution was this:

I changed this line;

```
WordApplication.CustomizationContext = WordApplication.ActiveDocument
```

To this:

```
CType(WordApplication, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application).CustomizationContext = WordApplication.ActiveDocument
```

Forcing the types to be correct.

Simple solution but took some time.

Thanks to Jules for pointing me in the right direction. 
(Points should go to you).